# DAC BLC objects

Tags: acumatica, dac

How I can access objects of DAC and BLC?

```
class BaseDACExtension : PXCacheExtension<BaseDAC>
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        BaseDAC dac = Base;
    }
}
```

Comment: DAC extensions shouldn't contain method definition. I recommend you read T100 training material to get a basic understanding of how to work with Acumatica Framework: http://acumaticaopenuniversity.com/courses/development/t100-introduction-to-acumatica-framework/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, just call `GetExtension` on either your base DAC or base Graph...

For DAC extensions: *(where baseDac is an instance of BaseDac)*

```
var dacExt = baseDac.GetExtension<BaseDACExtension>();
```

For Graph extensions: *(where baseGraph is an instance of BaseGraph)*

```
var graphExt = baseGraph.GetExtension<BaseGraphExtension>();
```

Comment: but i want object of blc in dac extensible

Comment: that sounds backwards. The BLC extension should use the DAC extension and its not typical to have methods/logic in a DAC. The logic should be in the BLC.

Comment: nothing will stop you from just passing in the graph to a method on the DAC via a parameter. It's just not normal or not recommended.